# How to set up TTL (Time to Live) of Azure Cosmso DB to "on (no default)" in Java spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

How to set up TTL  (Time to Live) of Azure Cosmos DB to "on (no default)" on Container Level in Java Spring Boot app ? Is it possible to do in yaml file or I have to write some code for it? Do I have to do it in bootstap.yaml or application.yaml? I wrote this config in file.yaml however I didn't sure about it.

```
spring:
   cloud:
      azure:
        cosmos:
           database: someName
             containers: someName
               ttl: on
```

Answer (score 1):

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-time-to-live?tabs=javav4

you can enable TTL for a container or single item using the java SDK, from the doc above this is the snippet for setting the TTL on container level:

```
CosmosDatabase database = client.getDatabase("database");

CosmosContainerProperties properties = new CosmosContainerProperties(
    "container",
    "/customerId"
);
// Expire all documents after 90 days
properties.setDefaultTimeToLiveInSeconds(90 * 60 * 60 * 24);

CosmosContainerResponse response = database
    .createContainerIfNotExists(properties);
```

you can also use the annotation in the bean class as well, ie:

`@Container(containerName = "mycontainer", timeToLive = 123, autoCreateContainer = false)`

afaik there is no way to set it using the properties, see https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/issues/875